# Usage of を in トップを{走る/行く}

Tags: particle-を

トップを{走る/行く} means for example leading in a race. Typically, if X is a location/space, *X+を+motion verb* means movement through/across X. Is トップを走る an example of such usage of を? (The runner is stationary relative to トップ.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is tricky because it depends on how you interpret "top".

Top does not point to a physical location/space in the racing track. It's an intangible concept, but the "concept" can be attributed with relative measurements such as 1st place, 2nd place 3rd place. Thus top, middle, and bottom exists. So does that make "top" a "location/space" or does it not? This can trigger a philosophical debate.

Depending on the interpretation, either answers make sense:

"Yes, because **トップへの道のり**を走る makes sense"

The runner is running through the conceptual location/space of "road to top-position/victory".

or

"No, because トップという順位を維持しつつ走っているが、**走っている場所・空間はトラックである**"

The runner is maintaining top position, not running across it. The runner is running on the location/space called racing track.

Understanding your question was the hard part to begin with, so I hope this provided at least some useful points even if it didn't fully answer your question.